# Remove all words in a string that contain any given substrings using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, csv

I have a .csv file that has a column containing text. For each item in this column there is a gene name and a date (for example 'CYP2C19, CYP2D6 07/17/2020'). I want to remove the dates from all of values in this column so that only the two genes are visible (output: 'CYP2C19, CYP2D6'). Secondly, in some boxes there is both a gene name and an indication if there is no recommendation ('CYP2C9 08/19/2020 (no recommendation'). In these cases, I would like to remove both the date and the statement that says no recommendation (output: 'CYP2C19, CYP2D6').

I have tried using the code below to remove any text that contains slashes for a single string (I have not yet tried anything on the entire .csv file). However it left the 07 from the date unfortunately.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('/(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')
s = 'CYP2C19, CYP2D6 07/17/2020'
pattern.sub('', s)
```

Output: 'CYP2C19, CYP2D6 07'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to just take the date out of the string, and then split it as you please. Note this works for any number of dates:

```
import re
x = 'CYP2C19, CYP2D6 07/17/2020'
x = re.sub(r'\s*\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', "", x)
```

You could replace `\s*` with `\s` if you always know there will be only a single space separating the term you want and the date, but I don't see a reason to do that.

Note that you could now split this by the delimiter, which in the case of your question, is actually a comma followed by a space

```
result = x.split(", ")
# ['CYP2C19', 'CYP2D6']
```

Although in your csv you may find that it is just a comma (as CSVs normally are).

Combining the steps above:

```
import re
x = 'CYP2C19 08/15/1972, CYP2D6 07/17/2020'
x = re.sub(r'\s*\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', "", x).split(", ")
# ['CYP2C19', 'CYP2D6']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could take each column then split it :
for exemple let's take the following string :  column = ' CYP2D6 07/17/2020'
you could do : `m = column.split()` then you will obtain : a list like : `m=['CYP2D6','07/17/2020']`
after that you could simply take : `gene = m[0]`